# How the Sausage is Made: Would you please elaborate on why this question was closed?

Tags: discussion

I am not necessarily asking for a reconsideration, and I am not asking because I had an accepted answer (probably because I did have an accepted answer and looked at it again after a comment was added is why it came to my attention).  But considering that I don't have enough reputation to see the discussion details, and because I am trying to get a better feel on How the Sausage is Made, I am curious as to why this question was closed:

[Error on Trigger: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void CheckPreviousYearEntryByPhoneNumber(list) from type FreeWaterSchemeClass](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/365681/81648)

**Would anyone be willing (and able, if it does not break some written or unwritten policy to discuss) to elaborate?**

From my view it seems like the main issue was that a question was not explicitly asked. But that happens a lot where the question is not closed. And they did include code and actual copied/pasted error text.  (The edit done was just for formatting.)

If there is a duplicate, I missed it.  I looked at every question on the first page of results for the following searches:

> "Method does not exist or incorrect signature" hasaccepted:yes
>
> constructor "Method does not exist or incorrect signature" hasaccepted:yes
>
> overload "Method does not exist or incorrect signature" hasaccepted:yes

I found many questions with the same error, but none for exactly the same reason.  And besides, the question was not closed as a duplicate.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: you'd have to hope one of the users who voted to close it would see this to get an explanation. I also do not see it as a candidate to close. Looking at it, my only guess is if you just read the `problem statement`, you may think it's one of those questions where they give a requirement they have and are essentially asking for a user to do their work for them (no attempt). However, that is clearly not the case when you look at the code.

Comment: Thanks, Kris. I am unsure of how close discussion works (or if there is any actual discussion), so did not know if people with higher reputation than myself can see into that discussion. I think you might be on to something regarding the `problem statement`.

Comment: It's the same as the other review queues with just different options on the sidebar - you can `Close`, `Edit`, or `Leave open`. Selecting `Close` gives you a radio selection of static options to select as the reason - which doesn't lend itself to any sort of discussion. You can see the basic workflow outlined [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/review-close).

Comment: Thanks again. For some reason I thought that there was more of a chat-type discussion for closing.

Comment: you'll have access to it soon enough :). There's more info on our options [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) and we do have community-specific reasons to select for closure that are based off [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I can't see what specific reason was selected in that question you linked as it's been re-opened (maybe Adrian/David can), but I presume it was `Questions about requirements or objectives should demonstrate the work or research you've done so far and ask a specific questions...`

Answer (score 2):

I'm generally not on the reopen side of any argument, but in this case, I really don't agree the question should have been closed in the first place. Sure, the question is only implicit, but the error message was posted clearly, as text, and the code needed to understand the root cause was included.

Comment: Thank you for weighing in. Obviously that was my gut feeling; but still being a relative newbie to the sausage making here on SFSE, I was thinking that I had missed something that might be obvous to some of you that have been around a lot longer.